# What is wrong with the property or indexer in the example?

Tags: c#

Code Here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program : iTest 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program pp = new Program();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public void  FistName
        {
            get 
            { 

            }
            set 
            { 

            }
        }

        public void  LastName
        {
            get 
            { 

            }
            set 
            { 

            }
        }

        public string  changeName(string nameToBeChanged)
        {
           return null;
        }
    }

    interface iTest
    {
        public void FistName { get; set; }
        public void LastName { get; set; }
        public string changeName(string nameToBeChanged);
    }
}
```

Error Code:

```
Error   1   'FistName': property or indexer cannot have void type   \\state.sd.local\Home\IT\ITPR13266\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication10\ConsoleApplication10\Program.cs   16  22  ConsoleApplication10
Error   2   'LastName': property or indexer cannot have void type   \\state.sd.local\Home\IT\ITPR13266\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication10\ConsoleApplication10\Program.cs   28  22  ConsoleApplication10
Error   3   The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item    \\state.sd.local\Home\IT\ITPR13266\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication10\ConsoleApplication10\Program.cs   48  21  ConsoleApplication10
Error   4   'FistName': property or indexer cannot have void type   \\state.sd.local\Home\IT\ITPR13266\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication10\ConsoleApplication10\Program.cs   48  21  ConsoleApplication10
Error   5   The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item    \\state.sd.local\Home\IT\ITPR13266\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication10\ConsoleApplication10\Program.cs   49  21  ConsoleApplication10
Error   6   'LastName': property or indexer cannot have void type   \\state.sd.local\Home\IT\ITPR13266\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication10\ConsoleApplication10\Program.cs   49  21  ConsoleApplication10
Error   7   The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item    \\state.sd.local\Home\IT\ITPR13266\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication10\ConsoleApplication10\Program.cs   50  23  ConsoleApplication10
```

Comment: How would you expect to use these properties?

Answer (score 3):

To properties function normally in the standard way, you need to remove the `{ }` and put only a `;`, when you need to implement a business logic into a property you will use the brackets and create a private variable to set and return.

Another error in your implementation: The properties need returns a `Type`, so it cannot be `void`. I think the first and last name is a `string`.

In your case, only need change to this :

```
public string FirstName
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string LastName
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

There is a shortcut to create properties: `prop` + <kbd>TAB</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>
Then you write the type, the name, and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1:** you have declared `void` as return type for your properties. it is not valid return type for properties. so you should declare proper return type to make it functional.

**Solution 1:** i think your properties are of type `string` so specify the `string` as the return type of properties.

**Problem 2:** you are creating `auto implemented properties` so you should have semicoln `;` after `get` and `set` .

From MSDN : [`Auto Implemented Properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

> auto-implemented properties make property-declaration more concise
>   when no additional logic is required in the property accessors.

**Solution 2:** you need to add the semicoln after `get` and `set`

Try This:

```
public string  FistName{ get; set;}
public string  LastName{ get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, your getters must have a return, or you can change to auto properties: `public string FirstName { get; set; }`.

You also have an error caused by using `public` in your interface:

```
interface iTest
{
    public void FistName { get; set; }
    public void LastName { get; set; }
    public string changeName(string nameToBeChanged);
}
```

Change this to:

```
interface iTest
{
    string FistName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    string changeName(string nameToBeChanged);
}
```

Note that interfaces always have public members, so there's no need to specify that (and as you've seen, you actually can't specify it!). And as Lucas points out in the comments, you can't have `void FirstName { get; set; }`. The syntax is `string FirstName { get; set; }`, assuming you want a `string` here.

Comment: The property cannot be `void`

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob - ha! I looked right past that part :)

Comment: The interface property cannot be `void`:)